# Converting Json to Pojo

Tags: java, android, json, gson, retrofit

I've recently decided to rewrite one of my older android applications and I can't figure out how to convert server response like this:

```
{
    "response": "SUCCESS",
    "data": {
        "0": {
            ... fields ... 
        },
        "1": {
            ... fields ...

        },
        ... another objects
    }
}
```

to regular java object (or in this case list of objects). I was previously using this method:

```
    JSONObject response = new JSONObject(stringResponse);
    JSONObject dataList = response.getJSONObject("data");
    int i = 0;
    while (true) {
        dataList.getJSONObject(String.valueOf(i)); // here I get wanted object
        i++;
    }
```

to get relevant objects and then I can put them into List, but now I'm using **Retrofit** library and I'm not able to find any clean solution to parse such weird object using gson and retrofit.

Thanks for any help.

Edit: What I want:

Send request using retrofit like this:

```
@GET("/some params")
void restCall(... another params..., Callback<Response> callback);
```

and then have List of objects in Response object. What I don't know is how to declare Response object, so it can convert that weird response into normal List of objects.

Comment: I would recommend using json-serialization libraries, such as `google gson`

Comment: I've already mentioned that I'm using gson, but I don't know how to parse that weird structure. You usually get array of objects, not "1":{},"2":{},... like map. I just don't know how to parse this

Answer (score -1):

You have many libraries around for this.. One i used was [json-simple](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/) There you can just use:

```
JSONValue.parse(String);
```

Answer (score -1):

look into gson too! i'm using it for all my projects, serializing and deserializing to pojos is remarkably simple and customizable (if needed, most things are fine out of the box)
[gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)

here is their first example:

```
class BagOfPrimitives {
  private int value1 = 1;
  private String value2 = "abc";
  private transient int value3 = 3;
  BagOfPrimitives() {
    // no-args constructor
  }
}

BagOfPrimitives obj = new BagOfPrimitives();
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(obj);  
==> json is {"value1":1,"value2":"abc"}
obj = gson.fromJson( json ); 
==> you get back the same object
```

Comment: Did you even read the question? it's JSON to POJO, not the other way round!

Comment: it's the same thing with gson. i added the fromJson command as well though.